# regex two place decimal with . valid at end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a decimal regex to allow number like:

```
12.

12.23

.12

0.34
```

but not:

```
12.@

12.2a
```

Most of regex I tried doesn't validate `.` at end.

Comment: Show your failed attempts.

Comment: Could you show us what you *have* tried?

Comment: why not use `parseFloat`

Comment: @bhb Probably because `parseFloat` doesn't allow you to restrict the number of decimal places, and because `parseFloat('12.2a')` returns `12.2`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist no where in the question does he say we have limit it to 2 decimal places. and `parseFloat('12.2a')` nice catch, i never knew this :)

Comment: Is `.` a possible value (for 0)?

Comment: @bhb I assumed the "two place decimal" part of the title meant that they wanted at most two decimal places, though that's not explicitly stated in the body of the question. It's possible I'm misinterpreting that part of the title.

Comment: I have tried /^[\.?\d]+$/ . seems working.

Comment: Clarifications:
*I want to mach only . as well  
*no length limit before . so 1234.1 is valid 
*without . is also valid like 1234

Comment: Is this value accepted : `.`?

Comment: @wared Yes this is acceptable

Comment: My question was : do you want the regex to accept a single dot? I personally don't care whether it's acceptable or not :D

Comment: Yes I want single . as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d*)|\d*(?:\.\d+)$/
```

It matches:

```
12.

12.23

.12

0.34
```

Comment: I have put . as optional ^\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*(?:\.\d+)$

but I also want to limit upto 2 digits after .

Comment: @aryankumar: No problema: `/^\d+(?:\.\d{0, 2})|\d*(?:\.\d{1, 2})$/`

Comment: it is not working now. Can you please check? Thanks!

Comment: @aryankumar: voilà `/(?:^\d+\.\d{0,2}$)|(?:^\d*\.\d{1,2}$)/gm`

Comment: It should work now: `/(?:^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$)|(?:^\d*\.\d{1,2}$)/gm`

Comment: I've added one more option at the end (?:^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$)|(?:^\d*\.\d{1,2}$)|\.              

working perfectly. Thanks @user278064

Answer (score 0):

The regex just have to check there is a dot preceded and/or followed by 0, 1 or 2 numbers.

```
/^\d{0,2}\.\d{0,2}$/
```

`\.` matches a dot and `\d{0,2}` matches 0 to 2 digits.

Finally, `\d{0,2}\.\d{0,2}` is wrapped between `^` and `$` to ensure the value that will be checked only contains a number formatted like that.

Comment: If 0 can be omitted before or after the dot, I think that matching `.` is ok as well. Some clarification about this from the author would be great.

Comment: @Cattode can you please also make for integer like 12 ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [***MDN***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
var filterFloat = function (value)
    {
    if(/^\-?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/
        .test(value))
        return Number(value);
    return NaN;
    }
console.log(filterFloat('421'));
// 421
console.log(filterFloat('-421'));
// -421
console.log(filterFloat('Infinity'));
// Infinity
console.log(filterFloat('1.61803398875'));
// 1.61803398875
console.log(filterFloat('421e+0'));
// NaN
console.log(filterFloat('421hop'));
// NaN
console.log(filterFloat('hop1.61803398875'));
// NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one : `/^(\d*|\d*\.\d{1,2}|\d+\.\d{0,2})$/`

Answer (score 0):

This seems working:

`/^[\.?\d]+$/`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

The first part of the expression `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?` matches one or more digits `\d+` that are followed by an optional combination of a literal dot and zero or more digits `(?:\.\d*)`.

The second part `\.\d+` matches a literal dot `.` followed by one or more digits, this is needed to match numbers like `.34`, `.3`, etc ..

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fR6tU7)

Comment: The downvote might be because they only want to allow at most two digits after the decimal place, so this doesn't answer the requirements of the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The OP didn't say so, and as far as I can tell this isn't a reason to down vote someone. I feel there is a hater around here.

Comment: That's certainly possible, though I took the "two place decimal" in the title of the question to mean limited to two decimal places. I could be wrong in that assumption though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist As you can see many of the answers didn't assume two digits after the decimal point, yet they didn't get down voted, and the down voter didn't say a reason, so I assumed he is just pissed off for some reason.

Comment: You guys are right. Down voters just vote down with eyes closed. lol